# Highcharts Export PDF offline by clicking external button

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, highcharts

I would like to create an external button named 'Export to PDF' outside the highcharts and hide the default buttons "Export" & "Print" in highchart export options.

I am using localhost for my project and have to export the highcharts to PDF offline. I have created an example at jsfiddle below.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3d406av3/19/)

```
$(function () {
    window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart('container', {
            chart: {marginLeft: 400},
        title: {
            text: 'Report',
                        x: 50,
            y: 130,
            margin: 150
        }, plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function() {
                            var val = this.y;
                            if (val < 1) {
                                return '';
                            }
                            return val;
                        },
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                    }
                }
        }, exporting:{
                enabled: false,
        }, xAxis: {
            categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30']
        },
        labels: {
            items: [{
                //html: 'Total fruit consumption',
                style: {
                    left: '50px',
                    top: '18px',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                }
            }]
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'John',
            data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6], 
            center: [0, 100],
        }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Total Visit',
            data: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                y: 13,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Jane's color
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                y: 23,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // John's color
            }],
            center: [-250, 250],
            size: 150,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }]
    }, function (chart) {
        chart.renderer.text('Total Visit', 120, 320)
            .css({
                color: '#4572A7',
                fontSize: '16px'
            })
            .add();

    });
    $('#export_PDF').click(function () {
      chart.exportChart({
        type: 'application/pdf',
        sourceWidth: 1700,
        sourceHeight: 600,
      });
    });
});
```

Can I know how to export the highcharts to PDF offline by clicking the external button that I have created?

Comment: To use offline exporting with an external button, you should use chart.exportChartLocal() instead of chart.exportChart().

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have the pdf export to work offline, you need to setup the highcharts render on the server side.

[`Render charts on the server`](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts)

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your code for button on click with this,

```
$('#export_PDF').click(function () {
  chart.exportChartLocal({
    type: 'application/pdf',
    sourceWidth: 1700,
    sourceHeight: 600,
  });
});
```